# c# AXL XElement Data to datagridview

Tags: c#, soap, xelement, cisco-axl

I'm busy with a application that extract data from Cisco CUCM to Datagridview with AXL/SOAP.

I get only the last record in the datagridview if I put the info to a combobox I get the compleet list.
The info what I extract with AXL is:
        
          SEP0014A815DB0D
          sk0000101
        
        
          SEP0022555E7E26
          AKijkindevegte
        
        
          SEP0018BAC8C6C5
          BT101139

This is my code:

```
            byte[] soapBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(soap);

            ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback += delegate { return true; };
            HttpWebRequest httpRQ = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(string.Format(@"https://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8443/axl/"));

            httpRQ.ProtocolVersion = System.Net.HttpVersion.Version10;
            httpRQ.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user1", "password");//Callmanager gebruikersnaam / password
            httpRQ.Method = "POST";
            httpRQ.ContentType = "text/xml; charset=utf-8";
            httpRQ.Accept = "text/xml";
            httpRQ.Headers.Add("SOAPAction: 'CUCM:DB ver=" + version + "'");
            httpRQ.ContentLength = soapBytes.Length;

            //Send the xml soap to cucm
            Stream stm = httpRQ.GetRequestStream();
            stm.Write(soapBytes, 0, soapBytes.Length);
            stm.Close();

            //Build the xml response
            XDocument responcedoc = new XDocument();
            HttpWebResponse responce = httpRQ.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            Stream responcedata = responce.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader responsereader = new StreamReader(responcedata);
            Logging.Text += "\n---------|AXL Response|---------\n\n";
            XDocument respdoc = XDocument.Load(responsereader);
            Logging.Text += respdoc + "\n";
            soap = null;

            //fill in the combo  

            DevicePhone.Items.Clear();




            foreach (XElement item in respdoc.Descendants("name"))

            {
               // DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                //ds.ReadXml((string)item);

                DevicePhone.Items.Add((string)item);
                string ds;


                    strDevicePhone = ((string)item);
                    ds = ((string)item);
                    label3.Text = strDevicePhone;

                    try
                    {


                        DataTable jmn = new DataTable("respdoc");

                        dataGridView1.DataSource = jmn;

                        jmn.Columns.Add("name");
                        jmn.Columns.Add("userid");

                        jmn.Rows.Add((string)item);

                        return;
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        //Interaction.MsgBox(ex.ToString());
                    }
```

Please Help
Whats do I wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a  new `DataTable` for each element and assigning this to your `DataGridView.DataSource`.  Predictably, this will result in setting a source containing the last item.

Move the creation of your `DataTable` outside the loop and add the rows within it.  Then assign your `DataSource` once after you've finished populating it.

```
var jmn = new DataTable("respdoc");
jmn.Columns.Add("name");
jmn.Columns.Add("userid");

foreach (var item in respdoc.Descendants("item"))
{
    // ...

    jmn.Rows.Add((string)item);

    // ...
}

dataGridView1.DataSource = jmn;
```

Comment: Hi Charles,

The solution that you provides works fine.
The last thing is I have <name>SEP000000001234</name> and <userid>hansom</userid>, Both I wnat to place in to Datagridview.

Thanks in advanced
Jan

Comment: I'm guessing as I don't have your XML, but try something like `Rows.Add(new object[]{(string)item.Element("name"), (string)item.Element("userid")})`

Comment: Hi Charles If have moth Items in the datagridview but the only thing what rest is that betwee two record I have 2 empty line. Thanks for so far

Comment: The most likely reason is that your XML has 2 `item` elements that don't have `name` and `userid` elements, or it has these elements and they are empty.

Comment: <return>
        <row>
          <name>SEP0014A815DB0D</name>
          <userid>sk0000101</userid>
        </row>
        <row>
          <name>SEP0022555E7E26</name>
          <userid>AKijkindevegte</userid>
        </row>
        <row>
          <name>SEP0022555E7F45</name>
          <userid>BP510210</userid>
        </row>

             </return>
    </axl:executeSQLQueryResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>

Comment: That XML bears no resemblence to the `item` query.  The only way you're going to resolve this is by debugging it youself - I can't really just keep guessing.  Step through it line by line and work out where your empty values materialise and why.

Comment: Charles, Thanks for the help and solution that you give.